Flutter_blue_plus how to handle GATT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
E/flutter (29165): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FlutterBluePlusException | setNotifyValue | android-code: 17 | GATT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
E/flutter (29165): #0      BluetoothCharacteristic.setNotifyValue (package:flutter_blue_plus/src/bluetooth_characteristic.dart:281:11)
E/flutter (29165): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29165): 

BluetoothCharacteristic.setNotifyValue (bluetooth_characteristic.dart:281)
<asynchronous gap>

how to avoid exception.
How to handle the exception, so that app doesn't become unresponsive.

One of my users is running into the exact same crash as well! There's this code for iOS compatibility at the end of the discoverServices code, it tries to call setNotify on 0x1801 service's 0x2A05 characteristic. What device causes this in your case.

Right now we cannot work this around because the crash prevents the return of the service+characteristics array, which is crucial to interoperate with the device. I filed an issue https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus/issues/955 please upvote, and add details: what device you use, what FBP version, what Android version, etc.

ok sure I'll add

Problem can be solved without a code change, there's an input parameter for the discovery call, see my answer.

You didn't include the whole call stack. But according to my experience this crash happens inside the FBP BluetoothDevice.discoverServices method, and at the end of that method there's code section for iOS compatibility right before the return of the discovery:
// in order to match iOS behavior on all platforms,
// we always listen to the Services Changed characteristic if it exists.
if (subscribeToServicesChanged) {
  if (Platform.isIOS == false && Platform.isMacOS == false) {
    BluetoothCharacteristic? c = _servicesChangedCharacteristic;
    if (c != null && (c.properties.notify || c.properties.indicate) && c.isNotifying == false) {
      await c.setNotifyValue(true);
    }
  }
}

That Service Changed feature is the 0x1801 BT GATT Service's 0x2A05 characteristic. Very few Bluetooth device has a problem with that, but fortunately there's this input parameter boolean subscribeToServicesChanged for the discoverServices, which gates this compatibility behavior, and it is enabled by default, but if you set it to false your problematic device should survive the discovery call (it'll skip the setNotify). So make the call (somewhere in your code has to be one) like this:
final services = await device!.discoverServices(subscribeToServicesChanged: false);

The core change here is the override of the default boolean parameter to subscribeToServicesChanged: false.

thanks, for your help. I'll try to include into my code.

Did it help? It must!
